# jQuery datatables-how to search text in column that has html tags in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

My page has search box to filter particular column data.The text in the cell is displayed using html properties like `<i>` and `<b>`.

So it is a challenge for me to filter the text with `<i>` or `<b>`.

Here is html code for search box.

```
<form>
     <span>EnglishStaffname</span>
        <input type='text' id='EnglishStaffname_search' value=""></input> 
</form>
```

The script to create datatable is below:

```
  function createWidget(table) {
    column_data = [
    {title: "User ID", visible: false, data: "id"},
    {title: "Location", visible: true, data:"location"},
    title: "Details",
        data: "details",
        sortable: false,
        render: {
            display: function(data) {
                json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                s = "";

                if ("subjects" in json)
                {
                    s += "<b>subjects:</b><br />";
                    $.each(json["subjects"], function(key, value) {
                        s += " - <i>" + key + ": </i>" + value + "<br />";
                    });

                    s += "<b>hours:</b><br />";
                    $.each(json["hours"], function(key, value) {
                        s += " - <i>" + key + ": </i>" + value + "<br />";
                    });
                }
                else 
                {
                    $.each(json, function(key, value) {
                        s += "<b>" + key + ": </b>" + value + "<br />";
                    });

                }

                return s;
            }
        }
    }];}
```

The table displays the details column like below

1st row :

**subject:**

-*English*:Meena.K

-*Maths*:Ramya.v

**hours:**

-*monday*:8

2nd row:

**English**:Kiran.K

**Maths**:Ramya.v

I have tried to filter details column for **English**  using jquery something like this:

```
$("EnglishStaffname_search").keyup(function() {
        try {
            item = $(this).val();
            table.column(2).search(item, true, false).draw();
        } catch(e) {

        }
    });
```

But the above is searching for whole cell not for only English.I have tried regex also but not getting exact match.

Can any one suggest me to get exact match irrespective of html tags?

Web page table:
[image]

Comment: Could you give us a small dataset to work with? I assume it's JSON?

Comment: Ya its JSON only.`{"subjects": {"English": ["nithya"], "Maths": ["divya"]}, "hours": {}}`...another set for else clause `{"English":["nithya"],"CS":["navya"]}`

Comment: can u post image of your datatable?

Comment: Do you mean the web page which has datatable?

Comment: yes @Nithya, asking you to add because i am not sure what exactly you want. As you have not added your full JSON to code. And if possible create jsfiddle.

Comment: @abpatil,please find the datatable.Want to search any name for `English`..since `English` is displayed in italic in one row and bold in another row ,I could not search it exactly.

Comment: @Nithya It is possible. Give me some time. Will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121836/discussion-between-abpatil-and-nithya).

Answer (score 1):

We can do it using [RegEx](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()#Example).
Try following code-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true
    });

    $('input[type="search"]').keyup(function(){
        var term = $(this).val();
        if(term =='') {
            regex = '';
        } else{
            regex = 'English:'+ term ;
        }   
        table.search( regex, true, false ).draw();
    })
});
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishbpatil1/ebRXw/2168/).

Comment: @abpatil..here is my json data..[{"userid":"2315","location":"x","details":"{\"subjects\": {\"English\": [\"meena\", \"teena\"]}, \"hours\": {\"2\"}}}", 
{"userid":"3009","location":"y","details":"{\"subjects\": {\"English\": [\"meena\"]}, \"hours\": {\"4\"}}}, 
{"userid":"3109","location":"z","details":"{\"English\": [\"suresh\", \"divya\"]}, \"hours\": {\"4\"}}, 
{"userid":"3209","location":"a","details":"{\"English\": [\"ramesh\", \"meena\"]}, \"hours\": {\"4\"}}, 
{"userid":"3309","location":"b","details":"{\"subjects\": {\"English\": [\"revathi\", \"meena\"]}, \"hours\": {\"4\"}}}]