# jQuery-how to match html tags for table column search filter using jquery dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The table td data is displayed by using some html properties like `<i>` or `<b>` etc. While doing column filter search with my own regular expression is not giving correct results.

```
$("#user_search").keyup(function() {
        try {
            regex ='username:'+$(this).val()+'*';
            table.column(3).search(regex, false, false).draw();
        } catch(e) {

        }
    });
```

This needs to match one line`"<i>" +username + ": </i>" + value + "<br />"` from multiple lines like this.

Is it really needed to match those tags which are only used in script and plainly displayed in web page ?

Comment: i think it should be `table.column(3).search(regex, true, false).draw();`

Comment: I have tried the above.`$(this).val()` will match all value.But I need only with `username: `

Comment: You want specific column to be searched? Post your table code.

Comment: Please refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095046/jquery-datatables-how-to-search-text-in-column-that-has-html-tags-in-a-table?noredirect=1#comment65537122_39095046